# Strange JavaScript Output when Multiplying

Tags: javascript

I wrote a quick JavaScript for a simple calculation. When I ran the script it had a strange output that I can't explain...

The script was, in its most basic form this:

```
for (var a=0;a<100;a++) {
    var b= 3.6*a
    document.write( b + "<br />");
}
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uKa2G/

Expecting that I would get straight single or no decimal answers, but every few lines there would be a huge decimal.

If someone can explain why it would be appreciated.

Comment: It that really `i` or `a`, or were you lazy? LOL

Comment: Don't mind me pressing wrong key when typing int question entry box ^^' 'i' should be 'a', it still messes up.

Comment: Short answer being that floating-point arithmetic (i.e. arithmetic with non-integers) has a certain degree of inaccuracy, because computers in general only approximate the value of a floating point number in memory (unlike integers, which can be modeled to an exact value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting no decimal then you have to `parseInt()`.

```
for (var a=0;a<100;a++) {
    var b= 3.6*a;
    console.log( parseInt(b));
}
```

Comment: @Paul missed it.  Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Not a problem.  I didn't downvote it, but possibly the OP is wondering about the answers like 320.40000000000003 and why that isn't 320.4

Comment: @Paul This should help OP http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/.  A good explantion on floating point:)

Comment: @PS13 I'm glad that I was able to help.